# In MySQL, is it necessary to use a FOR UPDATE inside a BEGIN and COMMIT statement?

Tags: mysql

Topic:

In MySQL, is it necessary to use a FOR UPDATE inside a BEGIN and COMMIT statement, or is the begin and commit essentially doing the same thing?

Edit: "is begin/commit essentially doing the same thing as a series of 'FOR UPDATE'"s?

Comment: If you use mysqli or PDO driver autocommit default value is true and not necessary to use commit

Comment: I don't know how your answer applies to my question.

Comment: Anyone? How do I bump this? :-(

Comment: Is your question whether the transaction isolates the data it works with the same way as `FOR UPDATE` statement does?

Comment: My question is whether a FOR UPDATE inside a BEGIN / COMMIT statement is redundant. Apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is whether a FOR UPDATE inside a BEGIN / COMMIT statement is redundant. I guess it isn't.. I think... because BEGIN...COMMIT only locks writes, not reads. Or maybe not?

Answer (score 3):

If you want lock the row that is `select for update` you should start the transaction, in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) we can see:

> Note
>
> Locking of rows for update using SELECT FOR UPDATE only applies when
>   autocommit is disabled (either by beginning transaction with START
>   TRANSACTION or by setting autocommit to 0. If autocommit is enabled,
>   the rows matching the specification are not locked.

You can use `FOR UPDATE` without start transaction but it's not safe...